# Enviar valores no onclick

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Estou tentando enviar dois valores no *onclick* do *HTML*, porém, o segundo valor fica como "undefined", como posso enviar esses dois valores para a função?

```
echo "<h3 id='$input' onclick='transfertoinput(this.id, $resp)'>$resp</h3><br>";
```

No javascript:

```
function transfertoinput(cl, valor) {
    document.getElementById(cl).value = valor;
}
```

Quando aciono a função, aparece esse erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: RPG is not defined
>       at HTMLHeadingElement.onclick (indexjogo.php:1)

RPG seria o valor da variavel '$resp' e 'cl' é o id do input de texto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tens de colocar aspas à volta de `$resp`. O que está a acontecer é que o PHP compila o HTML assim:

```
onclick='transfertoinput(this.id, RPG)'
```

e aí o `this` é interpretado como o elemento e `RPG` como uma variável, e não como uma string. Se tiveres no PHP `\"` à volta já vai funcionar:

```
onclick='transfertoinput(this.id, \"$resp\")'
```

e compilar assim:

```
onclick='transfertoinput(this.id, "RPG")'
```